# Reducing repetition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1

How can i reduce this ugly block of text? I wanted to use a for loop, but i need to refer to different objects for each iteration of ids .... temperature (i). Also, if i were to rename my objects to LB_Something0, LB_Something1, how could i incorporate that into the for loop?

```
    LB_NeedleHeater.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(0)
    FrmProduction.Needle.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(0)

    LB_SyrHeater.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(1)
    FrmProduction.Syringe.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(1)

    LB_PreHeater.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(2)
    FrmProduction.Station1.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(2)

    LB_DispHeater.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(3)
    FrmProduction.Station2.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(3)

    LB_PostHeater.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(4)
    FrmProduction.Station3.Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(4)
```

Comment: Is it WinForms or ASP.Net?

Comment: WinForms, it's VB.NET 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by naming your controls suffixed with a counter, like:

> LBHeater1, LBHeater2...

Then use that counter to find the control. Something like this:

```
For i = 0 to IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature.Length - 1
    Me.Controls.Find("LBHeater" & i+1, False)(0).Text = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(i)
Next
```

*Note*: Mark the second parameter to `Find` as `True` if you want to search all child controls as well. `Find` returns an array so pick the first one.

*Ref*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Did you mean "For i = 0 to IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature.Length - 1"?

Comment: Darn, find isn't available in VB.NET 2003 :(

Comment: Oh yes. *..This method is new in the .NET Framework version 2.0...*

Comment: In that case the solution suggested by Larry will help you easily. Or you could create a `FindControl` method yourself using this trick: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44928/FindControl-for-Windows-Forms

Comment: I think at this point, reducing repetition is not worth the effort/payoff ratio. (Say hello to lines and lines of code!)

But thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a array of controls and a loop will help you. However, you have to be very carefull about the order. Maybe using the .NET [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164106.aspx) mechanism would help?

Something like this:

```
Dim ctl1 As Control() = {LB_NeedleHeater, LB_SyrHeater, LB_PreHeater, ...}
Dim ctl2 As Control() = {FrmProduction.Needle, FrmProduction.Syringe, FrmProduction.Station1, ...}

For i = 0 to 4
    Dim Temp = IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal.Temperature(i)
    ctl1[i].Text = Temp
    ctl2[i].Text = Temp
Next
```

Comment: My bad, sorry. I missed it is .NET 1.1 and I will fix this. However, it will not be that short :(

Comment: Argh. Fixing this to fit .NET 1.1 make it worse. @abhitalks answer is the most accurate in your situation. If you dont want to rename your controls you could have a coma separated list of strings that are control names, and split it before a loop into it, but it is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use With & End With:

```
With IDS.Devices.Thermal.FrmThermal
    LB_NeedleHeater.Text = .Temperature(0)
    FrmProduction.Needle.Text = .Temperature(0)

    LB_SyrHeater.Text = .Temperature(1)
    FrmProduction.Syringe.Text = .Temperature(1)

    LB_PreHeater.Text = .Temperature(2)
    FrmProduction.Station1.Text = .Temperature(2)

    LB_DispHeater.Text = .Temperature(3)
    FrmProduction.Station2.Text = .Temperature(3)

    LB_PostHeater.Text = .Temperature(4)
    FrmProduction.Station3.Text = .Temperature(4)
End With
```